# Echad Ve'esrim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred twenty-one?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"David's cup, in the World to Come, contains 221 log [between 20 and 35 gallons], for the verse (Ps. 23:5) says, 'my cup overflows (רויה),' and רויה numerically equals 221." (Yoma 76a)

The significance of this figure, Kabbalistically, is that it equals the value of the word ארך ("long"), which is one of Hashem's attributes of mercy (ארך אפים) and is also associated with the aspect of G-d's Presence called אריך אנפין. (R' Shneur Zalman of Liadi, Torah Ohr, [Toldos 18d](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/toraor/6/18d.htm)-19a)

Comment: Connecting dots. Judges 14:8 האריה "the lion" mentioned twice